# Analytic Continuation for a Product

Tags: functional-equations, analytic-continuation

I was trying to solve the functional equation
$$\phi(x)^2\phi(2x)=x^2+2x+1$$
and by assuming that $\phi(1)=1$, and setting up a recurrence relation, I found the solution
$$\phi(x)=\prod_{i=0}^{\log_2(x)-1} (2^i+1)^{x-i}$$
However, this only makes sense for values of $x$ that are perfect powers of two. How can I extend this to non-powers of $2$ but still satisfy the functional equation?

Comment: $\phi$ is non-negative. Write $f(x)=\log(\phi(x))$. For analytic solutions you can find the power series expansion of $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: But the real problem that I am having is that I have a non-integer as the index of my product.

Comment: I meant directly from the original equation. I haven't even looked at that product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi$ is non-negative.

$f(x)=\log(\phi(x))$ satisfies

$$2f(x)+f(2x)=\log\left((x+1)^2\right)$$

---

**Since you are talking about analytic continuation**

For analytic solutions we can compute the derivatives at $x=0$

$$2f^{(n)}(x)+2^nf^{(n)}(2x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\log\left((x+1)^2\right)$$

Therefore $$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{1}{2+2^n}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\log\left((x+1)^2\right)|_{x=0}=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{n\left(1+2^{n-1}\right)}$$

Therefore $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n\left(1+2^{n-1}\right)}x^n$$

and

$$\phi(x)=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n\left(1+2^{n-1}\right)}x^n\right)$$

Comment: Wow, beautiful! Thank you!